# Load multiple dataset using a loop r

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to replicate the same code for about 270 datasets: `houses` and `village`.

I have one pair of dataset for every village i.e. houses_1 village_1, houses_2 village_2 and so on.

Here is my code:

```
houses = read.csv("gis/village/houses_1.csv")
village = read.csv("gis/village/village_1.csv")
coordinates(houses)<-~LAT+LON
proj4string(houses) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
coordinates(village)<-~LAT+LON
proj4string(village) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
houses@data$dist_center <- apply(t(gDistance(houses,village,byid = TRUE)),MARGIN = 1, FUN = "min")
library(foreign)
houses <- data.frame(houses)
write.dta(houses, "houses.dta")
remove(houses, village)
```

As I have so many pairs I would like to use a loop to avoid having to write 270 times the same code. Does anyone have an idea about how I could do that?

```
x <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
for (i in x){
houses <- read.csv("gis/village/houses_[i].csv")
village = read.csv("gis/village/village_[i].csv")
coordinates(houses)<-~LAT+LON
proj4string(houses) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
coordinates(village)<-~LAT+LON
proj4string(village) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
houses@data$dist_center <- apply(t(gDistance(houses,village,byid = TRUE)),MARGIN = 1, FUN = "min")
library(foreign)
houses <- data.frame(houses)
write.dta(houses, "houses[i].dta")
remove(houses, village)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for (i in 1:270) {
houses <- read.csv(paste0("gis/village/houses_",i,".csv"))
village = read.csv(paste0("gis/village/village_",i,".csv"))
...
write.dta(houses, paste0("houses",i,".dta"))
```

Also, you're missing the `}` at the end of the loop.